# Iterating over a dictionary and creating new one inside a for loop preserving order

Tags: python, loops, sorting, dictionary

I have code that is opening a file and reading a dictionary that is inside a dictionary. I want to take all the values from the key "time" and all the values from the key "close" and join them together as a key:value pair in a separate dictionary. My code achieves this however, I need the resulting dictionary to be ordered the same way it was from the dictionary i'm pulling from since they are dates. For some reason after the 3rd iteration the dates begin to get scrambled inside the new dictionary i've created. Any way to fix this?

Here's the sample

```
import json
import datetime

dict={}

def parsehistory():

    file = json.load(open('histoday.json')) #open file
        for i in range(len(file["Data"])): #iterate through subdictionaries
            time  = file["Data"][i]["time"] #get all values from key "time"
            close = file["Data"][i]["close"] #get all values from key "close"
            convert = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time).strftime('%m-%d-%Y') #convert time from unix to UTC
            dict[convert] = close #join values

            print(dict)
```

Here is a sample of the output which is clearly not ordered by date like which it came {'02-05-2018': 6937.08, '02-03-2018': 9251.27, '02-06-2018': 7701.25, '02-21-2018': 10481.66,}

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Prior to Python 3.6, dictionary keys are not ordered, and even then not always in the way you expect. Consider using  `collections.OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python dictionnaries are not ordered by default. You can create an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want to remember the order of insertions.

Just replace your initialization of `dict` with:

```
dict = collections.OrderedDict()
```

The dictionnary will however be ordered by insertion order, not by date.

Comment: This worked! I also had to add import collections in order to use that command. Thank you!